# How do I remove spaces while importing flat file containing intermediate blank lines?

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a very simple text file that contains two comma separated values that is about 100 lines long.  This file is created by an automated process (that I cannot control) and I import this file into SQL via SSIS.

My job works very well except when there is a blank line within the file.  By this, I mean it is completely blank - no commas or other characters.  When this exists in the file, the record directly after it will be imported with **two spaces** before the imported value.

For example, if the text line contains this "ABC,123", the imported SQL value will be "  ABC" for the first column.  I have tried to remove this by using a derived column with the TRIM statement, but that had no effect.  The REPLACE function also did not work.  The really strange part is that if I add a Data Viewer directly before the data flow Destination, the value looks fine.  I even added asterisks so that I could "see" the spaces if they exist, like this:

```
"*" + REPLACE([Column 0]," ","") + "*"
```

This is an **extremely** annoying issue, and I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.
Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. You can use `Script Component` transformation inside the *Data Flow Task* to clean the data.

- Here is a sample file that represents the data similar to your issue. Notice the second line with two spaces and no actual data.

[image: file with issue]

- When the file was imported directly into the table using a flat file source and OLE DB Destination, there was a blank issue before the second row imported into the file.

[image: invalid data]

- To fix the issue a script component transformation has to be introduced between flat file and OLE DB destination. When you drag and drop a script component, select *Transformation*.

[image: transformation]

- Your data flow task would look something like this.

[image: data flow task]

- Double-click on the script component to bring the Script Transformation Editor. On the Input columns, select the first column that is being read from your file. Here in this case, the column is `Name`.

[image: input columns]

- On the Inputs and Outputs section, create a new column named `CleansedData` of data type `string`. This new column will hold the clean output which is devoid of spaces.

[image: inputs and outputs]

- On the Script section, click on the Edit script button to bring the Script editor.

[image: script]

- Within the script editor, change the code in the method `Input0_ProcessInputRow` as shown below. this code replace the carriage return + line feed with blank text and then trims any spaces surrounding the text.

*Script code*:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Row.CleansedData = Row.Name.Replace(@"\r\n", string.Empty).Trim();
}
```

[image: script code]

- Now, in your OLE DB destination, replace your old column with this new column `CleansedData` in the column mapping section.
- After making the above changes, the package was executed against the same file containing blank spaces. this time no spaces were inserted before the second row.

Hope that helps.

[image: clean data]

Comment: Siva - THANKS for your very detailed reply.  Would there be a benefit to you using this one, as opposed to just doing the REPLACE within a Derived Column directly?

Comment: Siva - Thanks for the clarification & the great write up.  You earned your "accepted answer" classification (with the understanding that the expression method is an alternative).

Answer (score 1):

Got it - someone else replied to this in another forum. I needed to remove the invisible CRLF characters that were coming across like this:

```
LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE([Column 0],"\n",""),"\r",""))
```

Answer (score 1):

This was very helpful!  I did not need to scrub for spaces but rather datetime scrubbing, and this post showed me exactly what I needed.

This might not be the correct forum to post this, but here is a snippet to my code:

```
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    string str_test = "";

    try
    {
        str_test = Row.SomeDate;

        if (str_test.Length == 8)
        {
            // date example: 20151231
            str_test = str_test.Insert(6, @"/");
            str_test = str_test.Insert(4, @"/");

            dt = Convert.ToDateTime(str_test);
            Row.CleansedDate = Row.SomeDate.;
        }
        else
        {
            // test for some other date
            dt = Convert.ToDateTime(str_test);
            Row.CleansedDate = Row.SomeDate;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // this is not a date, return nothing
        Row.CleansedDate = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select {CR}{CL} in Row Delimiter drop box under Columns menu.